# Theorem 3.2. Rudin functional analysis, $f_1 \leq p$ on $M_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I cannot understand one small implication in such theorem

> Suppose
>
> (a) $M$ is a subspace of a real vector space $X$
>
> (b) $p : X \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $$ p(x+y) \leq p(x) + p(y)
> > \;\text{and}\; p(tx) = tp(x) $$ if $x \in X$ and $y \in X, t \geq 0$
>
> (c) $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ is linear and $f(x) \leq p(x)$ on $M$.
>
> Then there exists a linear $\Lambda : X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$
>  \Lambda x = f(x) \; , x \in M $$ and $$
>  -p(-x) \leq \Lambda x \leq p(x) \;,\; x \in X $$

Proof:

If $M \neq X$ we pick $x_1 \in X$,$x \notin M$ and define
$$
M_1 = \left\{ x + t x_1 : x \in M, t \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$
we have $M_1$ is a vector space. Moreover we can derive
$$
f(x) + f(y) \leq p(x - x_1) + p(y - x_1)
$$
We define also $\alpha$ as the least upper bound of $f(x) - p(x - x_1)$ (by varying $x \in M$. We can write the two inequalities

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
f(x) - \alpha \leq p(x - x_1) & (2)\\
f(x) + \alpha \leq p(y - x_1) & (3)
\end{array}
$$

And on $M_1$ we define
$$
f_1(x + tx_1) = f(x) + t\alpha \;\;\; (4)
$$

There's this specific bit I don't get

> Take $t > 0$ replace $x$ by $t^{-1}x$ in (2) and $y$ by $t^{-1}y$ in
>   (3), and multiply the resulting inequalities by $t$. In combination
>   with (4) this proves that $f_1 \leq p$ on $M_1$.

How exactly doing the mentioned steps we get $f_1 \leq p$ on $M_1$?
Doing the steps mentioned I got

$$
f_1(x - t\alpha) + f_1(y + t \alpha) = f_1(x + y) \leq p(x - tx_1) + p(y + t x_1),
$$

But I still struggle to arrive at the same conclusion

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily adding the two inequalities. If you consider them separately and look at the cases $t>0$ and $t<0$ you will get $f_1 \leq p$ easily.

Comment: I missed that... Silly related question, is the purpose of this construction to prove that we can construct a space $M_1, M \subset M_1$ and we can define a functional $f_1$ that extends $f$ on $M_1$? (I'm asking because the construction itself doesn't seem to be used explicitly later in the proof).

Comment: If you can extend it by 'one higher dimension' by this method then you can prove that maximal space to which you can get an extension is the whole of $X$. So this step is very important when you finish the proof of the theorem.

Comment: Ok but apart from that final point (important of course), Consider when we pick the collection $\mathcal{P}$ of all ordered pairs $(M',f')$ where $M'$ is a subspace containing $M$ and $f'$ extends $f$ on $M'$. That collection isn't empty because of what we just proved, right?

Comment: It is not empty because $(M,f)$ is already in it!

Comment: Out of curiosity, the theorem states (in (c) ) $f(x) \leq p(x)$, shouldn't it be $|f(x)| \leq |p(x)|$? (I saw there's a typo in (b), I just wanna be sure (c) is correct as well).